# Does anyone know the SQL query to get a SUM for more than one column?

Tags: sql, select

I'm writing an app where people can do audits in grocery stores.

The answers (answers are "1" or "0") are in several columns (see screenshot) and all these answers are connected to an `audit_ID`. Does anyone know the SQL query to get a `SUM` for several columns where the `audit id` = x?

[image: Screenshot of the database]

The answer the query should return (based on the screenshot) should be `9`.

Comment: This type of problem is the result of using a bad database design,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try simple `SUM`.

`SELECT antwoord+antwoord2+..+antwoord10 FROM [TABLE] where audi_ID=1`

This query sum your all antwoord values.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to manually add all the columns, like :

```
SELECT
    antwoord
    + antwoord2
    + antwoord3
    + antwoord4
    + antwoord5
    + antwoord6
    + antwoord7
    + antwoord8
    + antwoord9
    + antwoord10
FROM table 
WHERE audit_id = ?
```

However, the best approach here would be to change your database design so it fits better your use case. Actually, what you need is a table with 3 columns :

```
audit_id
question_id
answer
```

First two columns combined are the primary key of the table. Each answer generates a new row.

Then you can just go :

```
select sum(answer) from table where audit_id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1;
1   1   1   1   1   1
2   3   3   3   3   3

select a ,sum(b+c+d+e+f) over (partition by a ) from
Table1;
1   5
2   15
```

fro your table, the query is:

```
select  audit_id,sum(antwoord+antwoord2+antwoord3+antwoord4+antwoord5+
antwoord6+antwoord7+antwoord8+antwoord9+antwoord10) over (partition by 
audit_id ) from
Tablename;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `+` operator.

```
SELECT antwoord
       + antwoord2
       ...
       + antwoord10
       FROM answers
       WHERE audit_id = x;
```